# pySpark convert result of mapPartitions to spark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a job requires to run on a partitioned spark dataframe, and the process looks like:

```
rdd = sp_df.repartition(n_partitions, partition_key).rdd.mapPartitions(lambda x: some_function(x))
```

The result is an `rdd` of `pandas.dataframe`,

```
type(rdd) => pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD
type(rdd.collect()[0]) => pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

and `rdd.glom().collect()` returns result like:

```
[[df1], [df2], ...]
```

Now I hope to convert the result to a spark dataframe, the way I did is:

```
sp = None
for i, partition in enumerate(rdd.collect()):
    if i == 0:
        sp = spark.createDataFrame(partition)
    else:
        sp = sp.union(spark.createDataFrame(partition))

return sp
```

However, the result could be huge and `rdd.collect()` may exceed driver's memory, so I need to avoid `collect()` operation. Is there a way to address the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could just run a `rdd.toDF()`. Or, `spark.createDataFrame(rdd)`

Comment: @samakart, not really, it results in error `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` , I guess it only works for `Row`.

Comment: no, you have to submit a proper schema. in you case it just cant figure out the types i suppose. There is schema parameter to createDataFrame. It also accepts an sql like string. I havent found anywhere a doc to this syntax. But it is just sql standard.

Comment: @dre-hh is [this](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/adding-structtype-columns-to-spark-dataframes-b44125409803) what you're looking for?

Comment: yes and no :).  so yeah, this is one way to provide the schema as python types. but the schema parameter also accepts a shorter sql dsl notation. eg.
`createDataFrame(x, schema="uuid_id STRING, url STRING, title STRING")` 
I tried to find what types it support in the doc, but those are basically analogies of the python datatypes in SQL notation

Comment: ... forget to mention createDataFrame from rdd wont work with pandasDataframe as the rdd value. The value must a be a supported pure python datascructure. You can use a list of rdd.Row types for example
see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=createdataframe#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame

Comment: v nice question.  let's see what you/answerers found out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stay with rdd api. `mapPartitions` accepts an iterator of a type and expects an iterator of another type as result. A pandas_df is not an iterator type `mapPartitions` can deal with directly. If you must work with pandas api, you can just create a proper generator from `pandas.iterrows`

This way your overall `mapPartitions` result will be a single rdd of your row type instead of an rdd of pandas dataframes. such rdd can be seamlessly converted into a dataframe back with on-the-fly schema discovery

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

def some_fuction(iter):
  pandas_df = some_pandas_result(iter)
  for index, row in pandas_df.iterrows():
     yield Row(id=index, foo=row['foo'], bar=row['bar'])


rdd = sp_df.repartition(n_partitions, partition_key).rdd.mapPartitions(lambda x: some_function(x))
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
```

Comment: so these methods require to know the columns of the produced pandas data frame in advance?

Comment: Thanks for taking your time digging in this problem. I resolved it by your suggestion: converting to `Row` and then `createDataFrame`. The code I applied is to append each row of `pandas data frame` into a list of `Row` object: `row_list.append(Row(**row_dict))`

Comment: Nice that it also works dynamically like this. I was not sure. Give also the pandas udf (answer below) a spin one day. The disadvantage is, that you need to specify the proper type of the row type. But it will use `apache airflow`, using modern cpu SIMD instructions and the conversion from pandas to dataframe will happen behind the scences in way more optimized code

Comment: @MJeremy well done, i'll take note of `row_list.append(Row(**row_dict))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a new pandas [grouped udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#grouped-map) directly on the datframe instead of `rdd.mapPartitions` . The function itself accepts a group as pandas df and returns pandas df.

When it is used together with a spark dataframe apply api , spark automatically combines the partioned pandas dataframes into a new spark 
dataframe.

```
# a grouped pandas_udf receives the whole group as a pandas dataframe
# it must also return a pandas dataframe
# the first schema string parameter must describe the return dataframe schema

# in this example the result dataframe contains 2 columns id and value
@pandas_udf("id long, value double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def some_function(pdf):
    return pdf.apply(some_pdf_func)

df.groupby(df.partition_key).apply(some_function).show()
```

Comment: interesting but actually less versatile than @MJeremy's approach of `row_list.append(Row(**row_dict))` that handles arbitrary column lengths and types

Answer (score -1):

You can do :

```
sp = None 
def f(x):
 sp = spark.createDataFrame(x)
 return (sp)
sp = sp.union(rdd.foreach(f))
```

Refer :

[Spark SQL DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)

[Spark RDD](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyspark/pyspark_rdd.htm)

UPVOTE IF WORKS

Comment: Hi, thanks for digging in. I am afraid it does not work. `sp=None` => `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'union'` ; `foreach` => `SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers`