# Spark: How to correctly transform dataframe by mapInPandas

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to transform spark dataframe with 10k rows by latest spark 3.0.1 function [mapInPandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html).

Expected output: mapped pandas_function() transforms one row to three, so output transformed_df should have 30k rows

Current output: I'm getting 3 rows with 1 core and 24 rows with 8 cores.

INPUT: respond_sdf has 10k rows

```
+-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------+     
|url  |content                                                            |
+-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|api_1|{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }   |
|api_2|{'api': ['api_2', 'api_2', 'api_2'],'A': [7,8,9], 'B': [10,11,12] }|
|api_1|{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }   |
|api_2|{'api': ['api_2', 'api_2', 'api_2'],'A': [7,8,9], 'B': [10,11,12] }|
|api_1|{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }   |
|api_2|{'api': ['api_2', 'api_2', 'api_2'],'A': [7,8,9], 'B': [10,11,12] }|
|api_1|{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }   |
|api_2|{'api': ['api_2', 'api_2', 'api_2'],'A': [7,8,9], 'B': [10,11,12] }|
|api_1|{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }   |
|api_2|{'api': ['api_2', 'api_2', 'api_2'],'A': [7,8,9], 'B': [10,11,12] }|
|api_1|{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }   |
|api_2|{'api': ['api_2', 'api_2', 'api_2'],'A': [7,8,9], 'B': [10,11,12] }|
|api_1|{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }   |
|api_2|{'api': ['api_2', 'api_2', 'api_2'],'A': [7,8,9], 'B': [10,11,12] }|
|api_1|{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }   |
|api_2|{'api': ['api_2', 'api_2', 'api_2'],'A': [7,8,9], 'B': [10,11,12] }|
|api_1|{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }   |
|api_2|{'api': ['api_2', 'api_2', 'api_2'],'A': [7,8,9], 'B': [10,11,12] }|
|api_1|{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }   |
|api_2|{'api': ['api_2', 'api_2', 'api_2'],'A': [7,8,9], 'B': [10,11,12] }|
+-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
Input respond_sdf has 10000 rows
```

OUTPUT A) 3 rows - with 1 core - .master('local [[1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html)]')

```
{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }    (0 + 1) / 1]
+-----+---+---+                                                                 
|  api|  A|  B|
+-----+---+---+
|api_1|  1|  4|
|api_1|  2|  5|
|api_1|  3|  6|
+-----+---+---+

{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }
 Output transformed_df has 3 rows
```

OUTPUT B) 24 rows - with 8 cores - .master('local[8]')

```
{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }    (0 + 1) / 1]
{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }                
{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }
{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }
{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }
{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }
{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }
{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }
+-----+---+---+
|  api|  A|  B|
+-----+---+---+
|api_1|  1|  4|
|api_1|  2|  5|
|api_1|  3|  6|
|api_1|  1|  4|
|api_1|  2|  5|
|api_1|  3|  6|
|api_1|  1|  4|
|api_1|  2|  5|
|api_1|  3|  6|
|api_1|  1|  4|
|api_1|  2|  5|
|api_1|  3|  6|
|api_1|  1|  4|
|api_1|  2|  5|
|api_1|  3|  6|
|api_1|  1|  4|
|api_1|  2|  5|
|api_1|  3|  6|
|api_1|  1|  4|
|api_1|  2|  5|
+-----+---+---+
only showing top 20 rows

{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }
{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }
{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }
{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }
{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }    (3 + 5) / 8]
{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }
{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }
{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }
 Output transformed_df has 24 rows
```

Example Code:

```
#### IMPORT PYSPARK ###
import pandas as pd
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType,StringType
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("test") \
    .master('local[1]') \
    .getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

####### INPUT DATAFRAME WITH LIST OF JSONS ########################

# Create list with 10k nested tuples(url,content)
rdd_list = [('api_1',"{'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }"),
            (' api_2', "{'api': ['api_2', 'api_2', 'api_2'],'A': [7,8,9], 'B': [10,11,12] }")]*5000

schema = StructType([
  StructField('url', StringType(), True),
  StructField('content', StringType(), True)
  ])

#Create input dataframe with 10k rows
jsons = sc.parallelize(rdd_list)
respond_sdf = spark.createDataFrame(jsons, schema)
respond_sdf.show(truncate=False)

print(f'Input respond_sdf has {respond_sdf.count()} rows')

####### TRANSFORMATION DATAFRAME ########################

# Pandas transformation function returning pandas dataframe
def pandas_function(iter):
    for df in iter:
        print(df['content'][0])
        yield pd.DataFrame(eval(df['content'][0]))

transformed_df = respond_sdf.mapInPandas(pandas_function, "api string, A int, B int")
transformed_df.show()
print(f' Output transformed_df has {transformed_df.count()} rows')
print(f'Expected output dataframe should has 30k rows')
```

Link to related discussion:
[How to yield pandas dataframe rows to spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65412532/how-to-yield-pandas-dataframe-rows-to-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry that in my answer to your previous question, the part that uses `mapInPandas` was incorrect. I think this function below is the correct way to write the pandas function. I made a mistake last time because I previously thought `iter` was an iterable of rows, but it's actually an iterable of dataframes.

```
def pandas_function(iter):
    for df in iter:
        yield pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df['content'].map(eval))
```

(PS Thanks to answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65466723/14165730).)

Comment: You are the star! @mck I up-voted all I could. Also your PS question as it helped a lot to get more understanding, how it all works. In the end, pandas UDFs are pretty easy to debug as spark df can be converted to pandas df and then  pandas expression that comes after yield in udf function  can be called directly for easy debugging.

Comment: @Dan nice, then you don't need to worry about debugging spark udfs in vscode anymore :)

Comment: not any more for this udf, when I know how it works, but it would save a lot of time if I could stop inside udf and debug in vscode, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a tool that enables you to stop inside UDF and debug in VSCode, check out [pyspark_xray](https://github.com/bradyjiang/pyspark_xray) library,  its [demo app](https://github.com/bradyjiang/pyspark_xray/blob/master/demo_app02/driver.py) demonstrates how to use pyspark_xray's `wrapper_sdf_mapinpandas` function to step into Pandas UDF that are passed into `mapInPandas` function.