# Converting each row into a dataframe and concatenate results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` in the format below, where `content` is a string column.

```
                                                               content
0  {'api': ['api_1', 'api_1', 'api_1'],'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6] }
1  {'api': ['api_2', 'api_2', 'api_2'],'A': [7,8,9], 'B': [10,11,12] }
```

and I want to convert it to the format:

```
     api  A   B
0  api_1  1  4
1  api_1  2  5
2  api_1  3  6
3  api_2  7  10
4  api_2  8  11
5  api_2  9  12
```

I tried doing this,

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(eval(row['content'])) for (rownum, row) in df.iterrows()])
```

which works, but it doesn't look nice. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: `df.apply(pd.Series)` should do it.

Comment: @Ch3steR it gave the same dataframe. `content` is a string column, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try

```
out = pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df.content.map(literal_eval))
     api  A   B
0  api_1  1   4
1  api_1  2   5
2  api_1  3   6
0  api_2  7  10
1  api_2  8  11
2  api_2  9  12
```

Comment: I got `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`. Presumably that's because the column is of string type, not of dict type?

Comment: @mck chain with art ~

Comment: This looks neat!

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use `literal_eval` to evaluate the strings in column `content` as python dectionaries, then create a new dataframe from this evaluated column and use `apply` + `pd.Series.explode`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

r = df['content'].map(literal_eval).tolist()
pd.DataFrame(r).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Another approach which uses `defaultdict` to merge all the dictionaries in `content` column:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(list)
for d in df['content']:
    for k, v in literal_eval(d).items():
        dct[k] += v

pd.DataFrame(dct)
```

---

```
     api  A   B
0  api_1  1   4
1  api_1  2   5
2  api_1  3   6
3  api_2  7  10
4  api_2  8  11
5  api_2  9  12
```